# using the PID of a process running in a remote machine in a remote command

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access

I am trying to start a program in a remote machine using ssh. The arguments of the program requires the PID of a different process running in the same remote machine. I tried following:

```
ssh -n -f $EX_ENV_1_USER@$EX_ENV_1_IP "sh -c 'cd bin; nohup ./BinaryName arg1 arg2 \\`ps -elf|grep other_process_name | awk '{ print $4 }'\\` 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &'"
```

however this always put an incorrect PID to the command line. After executing this, if i try to search for the process with that PID i find nothing (in the remote machine nor local machine). It is probably a program invoked during this command it self I believe. I still cannot figure out the issue here and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider using [pgrep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) ?

Comment: No! I think that seem to be a better alternative. Will try that out. Thanks.